# Python Dict list of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matplotlib

So I have made some progress with this but I seem to be stuck now. I have a text file with 3 columns, **databasename, date** and **transactions**.

I have read these columns into a dictionary using `defaultdict` and when I print out the dict i get something that looks like:

```
databasename [['5-08-2015', '250'],['5-09-2015', '29']]
```

I want to plot the date on the x-axis and date on the  y-axis and use the database name for the title. I am using `matplotlib.pylab` to generate my graphs.
The problem I am having is that I seem to be unable to properly loop through the list of lists in the dictionary to get at the individual data in the lists.
this is what the relevant function looks like:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(open((file),'rb'))):
        if not i or not row:
            continue
        #print len(row)
        policy, server, user, _, app, database, trans = row
        data[server].append(int(trans))
    for server, trans in data.iteritems():

        f = open('C:/CIS Shared/Python Scripts/GraphData/totalTransactions.txt', 'a')
        sums = sum(trans)
        f.write(server.replace(" ","") + " " + file[5:-4] + " " + str(sums) + "\n")
        f.close()
    totTransac = open(path)
    transacDict = {}
    for line in totTransac:
        servTransactions = line.split()
        try:
            transacDict[servTransactions[0]].append(servTransactions[1:])
        except:
            transacDict[servTransactions[0]] = [servTransactions[1:]]

    for key, value in transacDict.iteritems():
        print key, ":", value
```

After i run this i get

```
databasename: [['5-08-2015', '12'], ['5-09-2015', '10'], ['5-10-2015', '10'], ['5-11-2015', '9'],
 ['5-12-2015', '9'], ['5-13-2015', '10'], ['5-14-2015', '10'], ['5-15-2015', '10']]
```

The part I am getting hung up on is how I can loop through the values for each key and get to the individual data in each value. I can do the rest after that

Comment: what? i dont understand what your question is

Comment: I need to know how to use this data to plot the points on a graph

Comment: All you have here is a fairly large function that generates some data in a certain form and a seemingly unrelated "What do I do with this next to get what I want?" question. I may be missing some key detail but I don't think your question is "ready" for SO yet.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the upper 55% of your code are irrelevant to this? (And misindented?)

Comment: The part I am getting hung up on is how I can loop through the values for each key and get to the individual data in each value. I can do the rest after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The part I am getting hung up on is how I can loop through the values for each key and get to the individual data in each value. I can do the rest after that

So if I understand you correctly then you want to iterate through a dictionary which has lists as its values?

```
def process(value):
    # do something with the value

for key,value_list in dict_of_lists:
    for value in value_list:
        process(value)
```